# No Theme menu is available in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I installed a version of Visual Studio 2010, but it has no Theme menu. I installed it on some other machines but none of them has the Theme menu.

I can only use the default theme. How can I add the Themes menu to my copy of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Theme" menu is not part of Visual Studio 2010, so it won't be there with a standard installation.

It is provided by an extension called the "Visual Studio Color Theme Editor", which you must install on your computer first before you can change themes.

You can download it [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378) from Microsoft's Visual Studio Gallery website.